# My Transactions hasn't been confirmed for 2days+

Tags: electrum, unconfirmed-transactions

I am new to btc. 2 Day ago, i sent some btc and it hasn't been confirmed yet. I have learned that it s because of low fee. 
1. Should I be worried about this ?
2. I googled and see that pywallet would help so I tried to use it but it didn't work . (I used electrum)
3. How can i amend my transactions using electrum? So i can add more fee.

Here are my tx
https://blockchain.info/tx/ba2d6baa3b123aee7612ae69ba72ffe2c4a3d86b12bfe5022243de6e3486b630

https://blockchain.info/tx/6267278f33a764f5a06793b8afa7996133192d07cf108243c3c5a1ae4ae3592e

Please help I am so desperate now. And this is not  dublicate post.. I have been searching here and cant find any solution yet!

Comment: We get this question a lot.  Trust me, it's a duplicate, and your answer is in the linked question.  I see no reason why your question is any different.